# how can i dynamically bind each state to each checkbox when using map function

Tags: javascript, react-native, checkbox

I m doing something like this but the value is been taken as string and not as a variable with boolean value

```
        {question.data.map((value, i) => (
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <CheckBox value={`this.state.checked${i}`} onValueChange={() => this.toggleCheckBox(i)} />
                <Text>{value.question}</Text>
            </View>
            ))
        }
```

this is my toggleCheckBox method

```
      toggleCheckBox(i) {
         this.setState({ [`checked${i}`]: ![`this.state.checked${i}`] });
      }
```

need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with adding string interpolation around this.state

```
toggleCheckBox(i) {
 this.setState({ [`checked${i}`]: !this.state[`checked${i}`] });
}


{question.data.map((value, i) => (
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
    <CheckBox value={this.state[`checked${i}`]} onValueChange={() => this.toggleCheckBox(i)} />
    <Text>{value.question}</Text>
    </View>
    ))
}
```

Comment: that worked ... thanks a lot for your help. have a nice day. :)